# InputStream.read(byte[], 0 length) stops early?

Tags: java, servlets, inputstream

I have been writing something to read a request stream (containing gzipped data) from an incoming HttpServletRequest ('request' below), however it appears that the normal InputStream read method doesn't actually read all content?

My code was:

```
InputStream requestStream = request.getInputStream();
if ((length = request.getContentLength()) != -1)
{
    received = new byte[length];
    requestStream.read(received, 0, length);
}
else
{
    // create a variable length list of bytes
    List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();

    boolean endLoop = false;
    while (!endLoop)
    {
        // try and read the next value from the stream.. if not -1, add it to the list as a byte. if
        // it is, we've reached the end.
        int currentByte = requestStream.read();
        if (currentByte != -1)
            bytes.add((byte) currentByte);
        else
            endLoop = true;
    }
    // initialize the final byte[] to the right length and add each byte into it in the right order.
    received = new byte[bytes.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.size(); i++)
    {
        received[i] = bytes.get(i);
    }
}
```

What I found during testing was that sometimes the top part (for when a content length is present) would just stop reading part way through the incoming request stream and leave the remainder of the 'received' byte array blank.  If I just make it run the else part of the if statement at all times, it reads fine and all the expected bytes are placed in 'received'.

So, it seems like I can just leave my code alone now with that change, but does anyone have any idea why the normal 'read'(byte[], int, int)' method stopped reading?  The description says that it may stop if an end of file is present.  Could it be that the gzipped data just happened to include bytes matching whatever the signature for that looks like?

Comment: BTW, you may want to take a look at [GZIPInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html). Instead of reading everything into a byte array and then decompressing the data separately you can just wrap the raw InputStream in a GZIPInputStream and read the decompressed data directly.

Comment: Ah, the reason we don't do that directly is because sometimes the input we receive from other systems isn't actually gzipped even though it's supposed to be... :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a `while` loop at the top to get all the bytes. The stream will attempt to read as many bytes as it can, but it is not required to return `len` bytes at once:

> An attempt is made to read as many as len bytes, but a smaller number may be read, possibly zero.

```
if ((length = request.getContentLength()) != -1)
{
    received = new byte[length];
    int pos = 0;
    do {
        int read = requestStream.read(received, pos, length-pos);

        // check for end of file or error
        if (read == -1) {
            break;
        } else {
            pos += read;
        }
    } while (pos < length);
}
```

EDIT: fixed while.

Comment: by the way, you really shouldn't use the request length to read the data.  the read() method will return a -1 when it reaches the end of input.  This should be your indiciator as to whether the data is exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to see how much of the buffer was filled. Its only guaranteed to give you at at least one byte.

Perhaps what you wanted was [DataInputStream.readFully()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFully%28byte%5B%5D%29);

Comment: Yes, I have seen comments about that on other posts about this issue - it would probably work for me too, but while fixing this it seemed more sensible to just keep the one way of reading the output :)  Only thing is I'm not sure whether this will be slower than the built in method...  We're only expecting short (up to 20k maybe?) incoming requests though so it probably doesn't matter.

The output of the 'read' method was correct in terms of how much it actually read - i.e. for a 11k byte input it would state that it only read 7k bytes.  I'm just not sure why it did that!

Comment: It gives you as much data is available right now so you can process it before reading some more. This is more efficient than waiting for all the data first before processing esp if the data is very large.